# Rails app - How do you add new lines in pdftk?

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdftk

I'm filling out a pdf in a rails app with the [pdf-forms gem](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms) and I have the need for a dynamically created multiline string. (`foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are methods of some sort below)

```
"#{foo}" + '\r' +
"#{bar if baz}" +
"#{'\r' if baz}"
```

I've tried `\n` and  `\r`, and the combination of the two. That gives me the little square, and no carriage return.

I've tried `\u2028`, `U+2028`, `^p`, and probably others... I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in Adobe Acrobat. When saving the document, you need to have the options in the field set to:

- multi-line
- allow rich text formatting

With those options, `\r` gave me a proper carriage return.

Within Adobe Acrobat Pro:

```
 1. Tools
 2. Prepare Form
 3. Create/Double click on text area
 4. Options
 5. Select "Multi-Line"
```